# strcat causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

This causes a segmentation fault:

```
char str1[60];
char**array;

array=malloc( str_nos * sizeof(char *) );
array[i]=malloc( str_len * sizeof(char *) );

strcat(array[i],str1);
strcat(array[i]," ");
```

`str1` is taken from `scanf` and it's shorter than 60 characters. `array[i]` is from a dynamic array of strings.

Do you have any idea of what causes the problem? It happens only for a great amount of `scanf`s.

Comment: Either `array[i]` is too small to hold the extra data, or one of the strings is not null-terminated.

Comment: You should give more information on how you allocate array's strings and how you create str1. It might be that str1 is too large for array[i].

Comment: How did you allocate `array[i]`?

Comment: please provide more code. probably you attempt to write more data to the buffer than would fit into the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

At least two possibilities:

- If the buffer pointed to by `array[i]` doesn't hold enough space, then you will overwrite the end of the buffer, which will often result in a seg-fault.
- One of the strings isn't properly null-terminated, so `strcat` just starts walking through memory.

Comment: @harp: How big is the buffer?  How long is the original string in the buffer?  How long is the string pointed to by `str1`.

Answer (score 1):

Either `array[i]` is pointing to nowhere, or the length of the buffer pointed by `array[i]` is insufficient.

**EDIT:** According to the code you posted, the buffer pointed by `array[i]` initially contains uninitialized garbage. You can't apply `strcat` to a destination buffer that contains uninitialized garbage.

Either make your buffer to hold an empty string before trying to `strcat` anything to it

```
array[i][0] = '\0';
strcat(array[i],str1);
strcat(array[i]," ");
```

or, alternatively, start with `strcpy` and then do `strcat`

```
strcpy(array[i],str1);
strcat(array[i]," ");
```

Comment: You *can* apply `strcat()` to an uninitialized buffer? Didn't you want to write "You **can't** apply `strcat()` to an uninitialized buffer"?

Comment: @Flow: Yes, it was typo. Fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
array[i]=malloc( str_len * sizeof(char *) );
```

What's `i` here? If `i` is not in the range `[0,str_len)`, then you are accessing memory that you may not have permission to use...